# remove gap from android-gallery

Tags: android, android-widget, android-gallery

As you can see from the screenshot I provided, I get a gap on the left and on the right side of the gallery.

How can I remove it?

[image]

Gaallery declaration in my xml file

```
<Gallery
        android:id="@+id/gallery1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: gallery items always starts from center instead of left

Comment: then how can i remove the space.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10026845/gallery-view-is-not-starting-from-left

Comment: start by selecting the 3rd item